# Load data after Ajax request in a template

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, express, ejs

I render a page with the data that ejs puts together. when the user presses a  submit button a section (`thirdRow`)of the page should be refreshed with the new data that was submitted plus the old data. I got the new data in the db, I want to refresh the `thirdRow` that shows all the reviews.

basically my problem is the `success` method in the `$.ajax` . I could get all the data there but it seems weird to write everything over in html strings. There should be a better way.

I saw a method where I could put the `.thirdRow` into a template and include that into the main EJS page and also put that into my static public folder and do something like `new EJS({url : 'public/thirdRow.ejs' }).update('.thirdRow', data);` in this case is the `data` in the last code snippet the returned data from the success callback in the AJAX? How Do I get Access to the `EJS` There are alot of links for ejs can you show my how to include the `EJS`

I don't know if this is the correct method. How would you do it? I have a page that is basically made up of all the returned data and I want to click a button and have only one section have the new data.

One section inside main.ejs

```
    <div class="thirdRow">
        <div class="reviewSection">
            <% if(reviews){%>
            <% reviews.forEach(function(e, i){%>
            <div class="indivReview">
                <div class = "userRow row">
                    <div>
                        <span>user </span>
                        <% if( e.username) {%>
                        <span><%= e.username %></span>
                        <%}else{ %>
                            <span><%=e.user%></span>
                         <% }%>                        
                    </div>

                    <div><%= e.momented %></div>

               </div><!--userRow-->

               <div class = "companyRow row">
                    <div>
                        <span>Experince for</span>
                        <span><%=e.companyName%></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span> industry</span>
                        <span>online retail</span>

                    </div>
               </div> <!--companyRow -->
               <div class="voteRow row">
                    <div>
                        Vote
                    </div>
                    <div><%= e.vote%></div>
               </div>
               <div class="reviewRow row">
                    <div>Review</div>
                    <div class = "displayReview">
                    <% e.reviewText.split("\n").forEach(function(e){ %>
                            <%= e %><br>
                    <%})%>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="statementRow ">
                // make a div for each object
                   <% e.statements.forEach(function(obj){%>
                   <div class="indivStatement">
                        <% var arr = []%>
                        <%for(var prop in obj) {%>
                            <% if(prop !== "name"){ %>
                                <% if(prop == "question"){%>
                                    <% arr[0] = obj[prop] %>
                                <%} %>
                                <% if (prop == "result"){%>
                                   <% arr[1] = obj[prop] %>
                                <%}%> 
                                <% console.log(arr) %>



                            <%} %>


                        <%}%>
                        <div class = "question"><%= arr[0]%></div> 
                        <div class = "bar" data-result ="<%= arr[1]%>"><%= arr[1]%></div> 
                    </div>
                   <%})%>
               </div>
                <div> <span></span>
                <span><%=e.companyName%></span></div>
                <div><%= e.momented %></div>

            </div>
            <%})%>

            <%}%>          
        </div> <!--reviewSection-->

    </div> <!--thirdRow-->
```

inside client script

```
$(".submitButton").on("click",function(){
    console.log(datum)
    var empty;
    if(datum.reviewText == "" && Object.keys(datum.statements) == 0 && datum.vote == null){
        empty = true;
    }else{
        empty = false;
    }
    console.log("empty : " , empty)
    scrollFunction(".thirdRow", ".submitButton, .shareButtonSection")
    var data = datum;
    if(!empty){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "http://localhost:4000/submitreview",
            success : function(data){
                console.log("success")
                $(".thirdRow").fadeOut(800, function(){
                    console.log("this", $(this))
                    $(this).html(data).fadeIn().delay(200)
                })
                console.log(data)
            }
        })           
    }
})
```

I never used EJS on the client side. Allways used with express

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using EJS client side
https://github.com/tj/ejs/blob/master/examples/client.html

Comment: my question related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711804/loading-template-after-ajax-request-using-ejs