# Loading template after ajax request using ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I load a page with data sent from the DB. If there are reviews it would appear in a div called `.thirdRow` . when users click a submit button that means they are submitting their review and it should reload the `.thirdRow` with the new Data. I can't get the new data to load on submit button.

I see in the success method `console.log("testData  : " , testData)` consoles me the data returned from the post request. So it appears I have the data. I set up template using `type = "text/template"`. I never used that before so maybe I'm using that method wrong. If I reload the page I see the data(divs) rendered that the user submitted before but when I click the button the `.thirdRow` doesn't change  without reloading the page.

In the `type = "text/template"` part when the user clicks I get returned "Nothing there" that is produced from the else statement (you will see) so I guess `reviews` is not getting data somehow. I should also mention that `type = "text/template"` is on the same ejs page that gets the data from ejs on the server so I guess that's why it works when I reload the page `app.get(page)`

```
$(".submitButton").on("click",function(){
    console.log(datum)
    var empty;
    if(datum.reviewText == "" && Object.keys(datum.statements) == 0 && datum.vote == null){
        empty = true;
    }else{
        empty = false;
    }
    console.log("empty : " , empty)
    scrollFunction(".thirdRow", ".submitButton, .shareButtonSection")
    var dataClientFrom = datum;
    if(!empty){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            data : JSON.stringify(dataClientFrom),
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "http://localhost:4000/submitreview",
            success : function(data){
                console.log("success")


                // $(".thirdRow").fadeOut(800, function(){
                    var reviews = document.getElementById("reviews").innerHTML;
                    // console.log("review ::: " , reviews) //the ejs in the template
                    var testData = data;
                    console.log("testData  : " , testData)
                   var html = ejs.render(reviews, {testData : testData})
                    console.log("this", $(this))
                    $(".thirdRow").html(html)
                    // $(this).html(html)
                    // $(this).html(html).fadeIn().delay(200)
                    addBar(".indivStatement .bar")
                // })

                console.log(data)
            }
        })           
    }
})
```

main.ejs

```
<script id = "reviews" type = "text/template">
    <% if(reviews.length){%>
    <div> reviews : <%= reviews%></div>
                   <div class="reviewSection">
            <% if(reviews){%>

            <% reviews.forEach(function(e, i){%>
            <div class="indivReview">
                <div class = "userRow row">
                    <div>
                        <span>user </span>
                        <% if( e.username) {%>
                        <span><%= e.username %></span>
                        <%}else{ %>
                            <span><%=e.user%></span>
                         <% }%>                        
                    </div>

                    <div><%= e.momented %></div>

               </div><!--userRow-->

               <div class = "companyRow row">
                    <div>
                        <span>Experince for</span>
                        <span><%=e.companyName%></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span> industry</span>
                        <span>online retail</span>

                    </div>
               </div> <!--companyRow -->
               <div class="voteRow row">
                    <div>
                        Vote
                    </div>
                    <div><%= e.vote%></div>
               </div>
               <div class="reviewRow row">
                    <div>Review</div>
                    <div class = "displayReview">
                    <% e.reviewText.split("\n").forEach(function(e){ %>
                            <%= e %><br>
                    <%})%>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="statementRow ">
                // make a div for each object
                   <% e.statements.forEach(function(obj){%>
                   <div class="indivStatement">
                        <% var arr = []%>
                        <%for(var prop in obj) {%>
                            <% if(prop !== "name"){ %>
                                <% if(prop == "question"){%>
                                    <% arr[0] = obj[prop] %>
                                <%} %>
                                <% if (prop == "result"){%>
                                   <% arr[1] = obj[prop] %>
                                <%}%> 
                                <% console.log(arr) %>



                            <%} %>


                        <%}%>
                        <div class = "question"><%= arr[0]%></div> 
                        <div class = "bar" data-result ="<%= arr[1]%>"><%= arr[1]%></div> 
                    </div>
                   <%})%>
               </div>
                <div> <span></span>
                <span><%=e.companyName%></span></div>
                <div><%= e.momented %></div>

            </div>
            <%})%>

            <%}%>          
        </div> <!--reviewSection-->
    <%}else{%>
    <div>Nothing there</div>
    <%}%>
</script>
```

EDIT: it looks like `testData` isn't being passed to the template. I wish it was